# Markdown for ticks and crosses

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown, icons

I really like the tick marks in some answers to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/free-incident-management-tool-for-more-than-50-users).

This would particularly useful on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), where users ask us to recommend software with a list of features. In reply, we could list the requested features and whether the recommended software has them, letting the OP (and future readers of the question) decide how much he really wants/needs all of those features, or if some of them were perhaps just "nice to have".

E.g.

> [image: Yes] Runs on both Linux and Android
>   [image: No] Costs $2.99 (but is free for non-commercial use)

However, they are being created by [Imgur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur) images.

Is it possible to expand our Markdown to add a green circle with a tick and a red circle with a cross (maybe a few others, like question mark)?

I originally asked this on Software Recommendations Meta, and someone there suggested "GitHub flavored Markdown", with which I am not familiar.

Comment: Some Unicode characters might get close to that.

Comment: there are already ticks in Unicode: ✅☑✔ ☑ ✔ although [the shapes might differ depending on the font](https://superuser.com/q/1173773/241386)

Comment: ✅✓✔❌❎╳ just search for "tick", "check", "mark" or "cross" in a Unicode search engine and you'll have the result instantly

Answer (score 27):

You could just use Unicode characters:

☑  `&#x2611;` or `&#9745;`

☒  `&#x2612;` or `&#9746;`

Answer (score 12):

If you're on a Mac, you can press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to get an emoji selector, then select ✅ or ❌. It's not a solution but a workaround for some at least (if you don't want to c&p Unicode characters every time).

Answer (score 10):

In Windows 10 you can use <kbd>windows key</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to bring up an emoji selector (like [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337585/299995) mentions for macOS). You can then select ✅ or ❌.

Comment: ✔✔✔✔ Fantastic! That covers Windows & Mac. Is there something similar for Linux?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045915/how-to-insert-an-emoji-into-a-text-in-ubuntu-18-04-and-later/1045916#1045916 someone's covered this on askubuntu.SE 

Comment: Wow, amazing tip!!! Will be very useful. Thx ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is likely far too nuanced and site-specific to integrate directly into the Markdown language itself. A very flexible solution is already available (as you demonstrated in your post). You can insert *any* graphical element inline with your text using the current editor tools — seems quite flexible and extensible to be able to insert anything you need directly into your post. Google Images is [full of icons you can use for your post](https://www.google.com/search?q=icons&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X). [Unicode icons](https://tutorialzine.com/2014/12/you-dont-need-icons-here-are-100-unicode-symbols-that-you-can-use) will also work.

If you like the way this works for your site, ***then do it!*** If the feature/iconography is appealing to other users, folks will follow suit. It's a simple matter to right-click on what you see and `copy image location` to reuse any image/icon in your own post.

I know that's not as convenient as having a shortcut directly in the editor, but for every `tick` or `cross` one post needs, there will be potentially dozen to hundreds more wanted for similar purposes — multiply that by the needs of each site. Our cooking site once requested a way to highlight allergy concerns and vegan-friendly alternatives; Judaism the same to mark specific rabbinic advice.

I think allowing small embedded images is a much better solution overall.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that when I want to use a tick, I have to seek out a post uses it, in order to copy the link, which is probably enough to put a lot of people off. If this won't be done S.E wide, could we add it to just one of the sites?

Comment: Or, on the makdown help page, could we add a link to http://www.fileformat.info/info/emoji/browsertest.htm ?

Comment: That is, could make some mention of it on https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ?

Answer (score 3):

I think allowing emojis (`:white_check_mark:`) like Github is not a problem.

Some solutions:

- [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/) addon (browsers only)
- [Emoji to AHK](https://github.com/alexmick/emoji-to-ahk/blob/master/emoji.ahk) script (Windows only)
- AutoHotKey or PhraseExpress for specialized uses. In AutoHotKey, you can use:

  ```
  :*:\check::✅
  :*:\cross::❌
  ```

So that every time you type `\check` or `\cross` it will automatically be converted to the corresponding symbols. Remember to put the script in the startup folder.

Comment: This is excellent! I wasn't even aware of StackEdit. I just wish that we could this for all users without an add-on